# WPF Application with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wpf, deployment

I have developed a **WPF** application (Visual Studio 2012) with **SQL SERVER** (2008) database. This application going to run in multiple (above 5) systems via **Internet**.
So I have installed a **SQL SERVER(2008)** and **WPF** Application (**.exe** format) in **First** machine (is a server). And another four or more machines have only **WPF** Application (**.exe**) with **internet**. How to connect a database via internet to storing data and centralize the database.. it is possible??? please reply..

Comment: You just give it a public IP address and connect to it.  Since it is exposed to  the Internet you need top properly secure it.

Answer (score 0):

The broad brushstrokes of the method are:

1. Register a domain name.
2. Point the domain name at the internet IP address of your web server.
3. On SQL server, open up the firewall, turn on encryption. Open up ports on PC. Switch on security.
4. Now, you can connect to the remote SQL database over the internet.
5. If you are running SQL server  on a home PC, you need a dynamic DNS server, see http://dyn.com/dns/.